# Efficient way to convert n bytes of multibyte characters to unicode

Tags: c, android-ndk

In the native code of my Android app, I need to convert n bytes of multibyte characters to wchar characters. Unfortunately, it appears Android does not implement mbsnrtowcs() method.

I cannot put a `nul` character at the end of n bytes. Otherwise, I could have simply used mbstowcs().

One possibility is that I allocate (n+1) bytes in a temporary location, copy the initial src in it, put a NULL at the end, and call mbstowcs().

I am wondering if anyone has a more efficient way to achieve this. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) provides many [string functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations) to convert between unicode and char arrays. You would stay much safer if you stick to them instead of using other functions.

For example you should be able to use [GetStringChars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17158) to get bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding.

```
const jchar * GetStringChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean *isCopy);
```

[jchar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) is 16-bit, which I guess should correspond to `wchar`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My code is almost all native. The conversion is required deep inside the native stack.